Is it bad practice to use a computed property inside another computed in Vue 3?
I've been working on a Vue 3 project where I have a large number of records (up to a million) that require various computed properties. To optimize performance, I've started defining computed properties inside another computed property. This approach seems to work fine in my testing, and it appears to save memory because the inner computed properties are only created when the outer computed is invoked.
Here is a simplified example of what I'm doing:
const _users = reactive(new Map())
function insert(data) {
    return data.map((user) => {
        const record = reactive(user);
        
        record.state = computed(() => {
            return {
                    fullName: computed(() => `${record.firstName} ${record.lastName}`),
                    props1: computed(() => record.a + record.b),
                    props2: computed(() => record.c + record.d),
                    //...more computed props
                }
        });

        _users.set(user.id, record);
    });
}

Observations:
When using this approach with a large number of records (for example, 300,000 records), the Task Manager in the browser shows approximately 300 MB of memory usage. However, if I define the computed properties directly in the object instead of nesting them, the memory usage increases to about 900 MB.
Furthermore, adding a new computed property in this nested manner seems to add around 50 MB of additional memory usage. This suggests that using nested computed properties might be more memory-efficient compared to defining them directly in the object.
Questions:

Is there any downside to defining computed properties inside another computed like this?

Could this approach potentially lead to memory leaks or performance issues in the long run, especially with a large number of records?

Are there any best practices or alternative patterns I should consider when working with a large dataset in Vue 3?


Additional Context:

My primary goal is to minimize memory usage while still leveraging Vue's reactivity system.

The application needs to handle millions of records efficiently, so I'm open to any suggestions that could help with performance optimization.


Thanks in advance for your insights!
For more context, here's an example of the code in a project:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/pinia-store-nested-computed-z2rvtd

It's unknown what's your case regarding the performance. If it's crucial, at this point it makes sense to NOT use reactivity everywhere you can, as it's relatively slow. Or desugar computeds to watchers and refs/reactive objects in a way that could be efficient in your case. If you're supposed to calculate some record fields (fullName, etc) on record change, do this in a watcher. This also could be done lazily because there's a chance you don't need the whole million records at the very same moment

Vue automatically tracks changes to any variable, nested property or nested refs used inside a computed and unwraps any inner refs (including computed). From documentation:

If an object is assigned as a ref's value, the object is made deeply reactive with reactive(). This also means if the object contains nested refs, they will be deeply unwrapped.

In other words, the following syntax:
record.state = computed(() => {
  return {
    fullName: computed(() => `${record.firstName} ${record.lastName}`),
    props1: computed(() => record.a + record.b),
    props2: computed(() => record.c + record.d),
  }
});

is unwrapped by Vue at runtime into:
record.state = computed(() => ({
  fullName: `${record.firstName} ${record.lastName}`,
  props1: record.a + record.b,
  props2: record.c + record.d
}))

Vue does this all the time and is designed to do it fast, so the performance hit is not noticeable.
To answer the title question: yes, it is definitely bad practice, not necessarily because it wouldn't work or because it might be slightly less performant, but because it's useless, it's less readable and more confusing for whoever has to modify that code.
Avoid it.

To get more help optimizing your code for a large dataset, consider providing the data structure you're working with and specifying what's the end goal, so one could test various patterns with generated data resembling the one you're using.

Side note: frontend rarely needs to work with a very large number of records.
Consider moving the bulk of computation on a server optimized for whatever operations you need on that data and only send the user what fits on their screen. Consider batching, clustering, virtual scrolling and/or other similar techniques appropriate for your use-case.
Changing the approach in how you consume and present the data is likely to benefit your use case more than optimizing Vue, which is already heavily optimized.

Additional note, after looking at the provided example.
Here are two rather big flaws of the example you've presented:

you're listing (as in rendering) 300k users, but only 10-15 fit on a screen at one time. Consider using virtual rendering. There is absolutely no reason to have the browser render millions of DOM nodes outside the screen
secondly, it's a mistake to make all of the records reactive at the same time. I'm guessing they're reactive because you want to allow editing. But, in reality, only one is edited at one time, when the user types in the provided inputs. Consider storing all records as plain objects (without any reactivity) and making reactive only the one the user is currently editing. Whenever the "loaded" one changes, update its counterpart in the non-reactive source.

Applying the above principles will drastically improve your app's performance.

Try to add console.log inside the inner computed and you will realize that it is not being unwrapped.

@Nazarko, of course it's not unwrapped inside the computed. But what matters is what's outside of it, because anything that might consume it is outside. Add a log outside and you'll see it's unwrapped.

Or, better yet, show me a single case where the two syntaxes (with nested refs and without) have different behavior.

@tao here is an example
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/pinia-store-nested-computed-z2rvtd

@MichailoBanakh, I've added a few comments on what you've presented to the answer. In essence, you've presented an XY problem. Rather than asking how to render and/or make reactive millions of records without killing the browser, you should start by asking how the business requirements of your app can be achieved while rendering and/or making reactive the least amount of elements.

Yes, it's bad because this voids the warranty, this may lead to unpredictable results because the computeds aren't expected to be used like that. You won't find such usage in the documentation.
These aren't just nested computeds that are the problem. That reactivity API is used not inside a composable but some function that can run at arbitrary moment of time suggests that it's misused and again, this may lead to unpredictable results.
Considering there's reusable code that uses reactivity API (conventionally called a composable function):
function useMyData() {
  const data = reactive({...});
  const getter = computed(() => data...);

  return { data, getter };
} 

This is normal documented use:
// store.js
export const globalState = useMyData();

And this is normal documented use:
<script setup>
const localComponentState = useMyData();
...

This is not normal documented use:
<script setup>
setTimeout(() => { 
  const justSomeState = useMyData();
  ...

Even if it's technically possible to use the reactivity this way, this is a potential misuse and requires to have a good understanding of possible implications and Vue internals.

Thank you for the insights on using computed properties and the reactivity API in Vue. I understand the risks of non-standard usage, especially outside of composable functions. However, in my case, this approach significantly reduces memory usage when handling large datasets. For instance, with 300,000 records, memory dropped from 900 MB to 300 MB, and adding more computed properties only increased it slightly.
Could you take a look at my https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/pinia-store-nested-computed-z2rvtd example for more context? I’d appreciate your thoughts on this specific implementation.

The point is that you're doing is a corner case and it has a good chance to malfunction because you're abusing reactivity system and I doubt anyone can really explain what happens in this case without digging through vue core. And this creates a high risk of additional maintenance cost (= figuring out what happens and then painfully rewriting the stuff when it turns out it's unfixable)

Did you try to implement this with a watcher like suggested in the comment above? A watcher that specifically watches for the changes that are expected in your store. Or if the records aren't really changed after insertion then no watcher is necessary, this would be a waste of resources. Because this is how it's normally done when computeds don't fully suit your needs. A computed can be basically expressed with ref+watch. The demo doesn't show how the state is changed and why you needed this approach at all. I mean, when fullName is exactly recalculated?

Thanks for the suggestion! I did try using watch, but it led to even higher memory usage compared to using computed properties, especially with a large number of records.
The idea behind this approach was to create something similar to Ember Data—composable primitives for managing data flows, network/cache interactions, and computed properties, all tied to a model. I wanted to keep the model, its attributes, and related computed properties together in one place, making it easier to manage and maintain.
Thanks again!

This is very specific to the implementation of a watcher. They will possibly be a set of different watchers if you need atomic changes, not a single "deep" watcher. Consider addressing a specific implementation if you need the assistance with it. And again, you probably don't need that. I see what you're trying to do but this looks like a wrong design of a store. Generally if you mutate a record that has dependencies that need to be recalculated (fullName, etc), you mutate it in an action, and that's where the fields can be recalculated. With possible addition of shallow reactivity to optimize

The short answer is that you are leaking memory. I am sure it will be simpler to just read data from _users in your template but if you really need to define computed data in users then please read the long answer below
When you use watch, watchEffect, computed etc you are creating an effect which depends on some reactive data and will be re-run when that reactive data changes
Obviously monitoring reactive data has some amount of overhead so we need to clean up the effect when it is no longer needed. Vue does this automatically when the effect scope that created the effect is stopped/disposed
So if you have some component then it will create an effect scope for itself which will be stopped when the component is unmounted (this is a simplification, keep-alive exists). Then when it runs your component's setup function it does so inside this new effect scope and any time you call watch, watchEffect etc it links that effect to the effect scope so they will be cleaned up when the component instance is removed
The problem here is that the setup function runs in the effect scope, the computed callback does NOT. Any effect you create inside a watch callback or computed callback will only be automatically cleaned up if it was created during a synchronous immediate call
In most cases there is a simple solution: just create the computed functions you want state to contain before you define the computed for state itself
const fullName = computed(() => `${record.firstName} ${record.lastName}`);
const props1 = computed(() => record.a + record.b);
const props2 = computed(() => record.c + record.d);
// more computed props

const state = computed(() => ({
    fullName: fullName.value,
    props1: props1.value,
    props2: props2.value,
}));

This will provide a small performance improvement because updating record.a will recompute props1 and state but not fullName and props2
The other issue is that you are creating this reactive data inside the insert() function and I am not sure when that function will be called. If it is exclusively called during your setup function before any awaiting then you are in the clear but if you are calling it when some event fires then again you have escaped from the current effect scope and are leaking memory
Fortunately there is a simple solution. Create an effect scope or get a reference to the currently running effect scope; then explicitly execute that effect scope when you want to create a new effect
import { computed, effectScope, reactive } from 'vue';

const childScope = effectScope();
const _users = reactive(new Map());

function userToRecord(user) {
    return childScope.run(() => {
        const record = reactive(user);

        const fullName = computed(() => `${record.firstName} ${record.lastName}`);
        const props1 = computed(() => record.a + record.b);
        const props2 = computed(() => record.c + record.d);
        // more computed props

        const state = computed(() => ({
            fullName: fullName.value,
            props1: props1.value,
            props2: props2.value,
        }));

        record.state = state;

        return record;
    });
};

function insert(data) {
    return data.map((user) => {
        const record = userToRecord(user);

        _users.set(user.id, record);
    });
}

So long as we execute const childScope = effectScope(); in a valid parent scope then we are in the clear
Technically speaking you could use childScope.run() inside of a computed callback to "safely" create effects but I am sure that is a mountain of footguns

One more thing to consider is removing a user will not stop its computed effects in this case. They will only stop when your component is destroyed.
You can work around that by creating an effect scope for each user record and storing it somewhere, then creating all of that record's effects in its specific scope. You can call the stop() method on that scope when removing the user to immediately clean up your effects
